# Should data classes with redundant fields be used in android development?

Tags: android, kotlin

Converting `Flow` to `StateFlow` is a very common scenario.

This means I need two classes, a data class with fields of type `Flow` and a data class with fields of type `StateFlow`.

```kotlin
data class SyncWorkDTO(
    val count: Flow<Int>
)

data class SyncWorkVO(
    val count: StateFlow<Int>
)
```

Then convert `SyncWorkDTO` to `SyncWorkVO` in `ViewModel`.

```kotlin
syncWorks.addAll(syncUseCase().map { dto ->
  SyncWorkVO(
    scope = applicationScope,
    started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
    initialValue = 0
  )
})
```

But there is another solution, I can avoid the conversion by having a data class with redundant fields.

```kotlin
data class SyncWorkVO(
    val countFlow: Flow<Int>
    val countStateFlow: StateFlow<Int>
)
```

The code in ViewModel is similar to the previous code, but in the actual situation `SyncWorkVO` has more than one field, which can effectively reduce the amount of code.

**Should I use the solution with redundant fields? Why?**

#### first edit

Suppose I have a screen that provides different works for the user to choose to perform.

```
data class SyncWorkVO(
  val id: Int,
  val title: String,
  var checked: Boolean,
  val localCountFlow: Flow<Int>,
  val localCountState: StateFlow<Int>,
  val remoteCount: Long,
  val upload: () -> Unit,
  val download: () -> Unit,
  val getRemoteCount: suspend () -> Long
)
```

`Screen`

```kotlin
LazyColumn(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)) {
  itemsIndexed(viewModel.syncWorks, key = { _, work -> work.id }) { index, work ->

    val localCount by work.localCountState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    Row {
      Checkbox(
        checked = work.checked,
        onCheckedChange = { checked ->
          viewModel.syncWorks[index] = work.copy(checked = checked)
        }
      )
      Text(text = work.title, style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium)
      Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
      Text(text = "remote count: ${work.remoteCount}", style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium)
      Text(text = "local count: $localCount", style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium)
      Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
    }
  }
}
Row {
  Button(onClick = {
    viewModel.onUpload()
  }) {
    Text("Upload", style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium)
  }
  Button(onClick = {
  }) {
    Text("Download", style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium)
  }
}
```

The logic is as follows: When the user selects a work, `SyncWorkVO#checked` becomes `true`, and when the user clicks the `upload` button, execute `SyncWorkVO#upload`.

During this process, `localCountState` is `StateFlow` will keep changing to show the progress of the work.

I can understand that function should probably not be put in data class, but I don't quite understand why can't put `Flow` in `data class`?

Comment: Are these actually going to be the same flow?  If not, the narrower subtype is presumably strictly preferable.

Comment: @LouisWasserman what mean `same flow`? `StateFlow` is converted from `Flow`, so they are the same, do you mean that?

Comment: It seems very weird to me to put a Flow in a data class. Flow doesn’t have an equals function that makes sense as data, so the data class wouldn’t either. At that point, why would you mark the class `data`? Actually, why wrap these in classes at all of the classes only have one property? As for your question, can you give an example of how you would use this combined class? But overall, this looks very messy. A data class is for simple data, not flows, and certainly not StateFlows that are running coroutines under the hood.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I added the content of the question.

Comment: The purpose of a data class is to hold simple data so it can generate sensible `equals` and `hashCode` functions for you. If any of the properties use types that do not have sensible `equals`/`hashCode`, then the only benefit of using a data class is broken so it’s pointless. Flows do not have an equals function that can be used in this way.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks, makes sense, I see. But what is the best practice in my case? Displaying different progress bars on a screen requires the use of `Flow`, as well as some other attributes, such as `title` and so on. Separate these attributes from `Flow`?

Comment: It’s hard to say without fully understanding your design. I typically don’t have so much stuff wrapped up into a class, but when I do combine data into one class, I would have a flow of that class, which may involve some merging of flow(s) with static data.

Comment: `I would have a flow of that class`,  this class is `data class` or else?